# UIView doesn't directly show up

Tags: iphone, ios

This is certainly nothing but I'm in trouble with a UIView that doesn't show up immediatly.

Here is the code :

`SettingViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)reloadParametersDB:(id)sender {
    LoadingView* loadingView = [LoadingView loadLoadingIntoView:self.view];
    [dbService fillParametersTables];
    [loadingView removeLoading];
}
```

`LoadingView.m`

```
+(LoadingView *)loadLoadingIntoView:(UIView *)superView{
    LoadingView *loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:superView.bounds];
    if (loadingView == nil) return nil;
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [superView addSubview:loadingView];
    return loadingView;
}
```

It works because when I'm printing something in loadLoadingIntoView I'm seeing it, and actually the problem is that the addSubview is effective after fillParametersTables is done ...

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you could fill the table in a background thread, then it would be immediately added to the subview, regardless of whether all the parameters have been added yet. Just a question, is there a reason you're creating a new instance of `LoadingView` in your `loadLoadingIntoView` method rather than using `self`?

Comment: Yeah but actually, and because fill table is a bit long, I just want to display a loading view on-top of the current view so that the user knows he has to wait, and the application isn't freezed or something, do yo know what I mean ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return to the event loop in order to have your display update.  One way would be to put the lines after you set up the loading view into their own method and then use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to execute it.

E.g.:

```
- (void)doTableLoading:(id)loadingView {
    [dbService fillParametersTables];
    [(LoadingView *)loadingView removeLoading];
}

- (IBAction)reloadParametersDB:(id)sender {
    LoadingView* loadingView = [LoadingView loadLoadingIntoView:self.view];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doTableLoading:) withObject:loadingView afterDelay:0.1f]
}
```

(This code was written inside an HTML form and may not even compile...but it should give an idea of the strategy.)